# Encoding issue with Html.DisplayFor into an input value

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

My code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomOuvrage)
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomOuvrage)" />
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

Have you any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem with an html encoded value between "" ?

as `HtmlHelper.DisplayFor` uses `MvcHtmlString.Create()`

and [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

> Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

You should just use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.nomOuvrage)
```